# add key value pair in array_map php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
[{
    "id": "000060000000000071964708\/17\/201309:55:00"
}, {
    "column": "pcchrgcod"
}]
```

This is my out of my select query and adding of new key pair.

What I desire is:

```
[{
    "id": "000060000000000071964708\/17\/201309:55:00",
    "column": "pcchrgcod"
}]
```

What I tried is:

```
while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] =  array_map('utf8_encode', $selected_row);
    array_push($rows, array('column' => $column));
}
```

In my solution I used `array_push` but it didnt return my desired output.

> How to fix this ?

The output is result of `json_encode`

`UPDATE`

The array is from a select query. And on the return row of that query I want to add another pair of key value. That is the reason why I want to add another key pair value

`Additional Question`

Say this query

`Select column AS colunname from table`

And from this query I want the value of `columnname = 'column_name'` ?

Comment: I believe that the solution will be in fixing your query

Comment: @hassan i need to return the column name is it possible to return the column name together with the value in mysql?

Comment: that's what `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` do

Comment: @hassan lets say this is my query `select column AS columnname from table` how can i set the value of variable $column to result of query that will be named columnname ?

Comment: Check my updated answer, I hope you will get what you want. And yes fetch id and column both, because thats what your array is look like

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using array_walk, try below code,

```
$str = '[{
    "id": "000060000000000071964708\/17\/201309:55:00"
}, {
    "column": "pcchrgcod"
}]';
$arr = json_decode($str, true); // true => making it normal array 
$result = []; // output array
array_walk($arr, function ($item, $key) use (&$result) { // passing address of result
    $result[key($item)] = $item[key($item)]; // key => first key of array
});
print_r($result); // output of the snippet
```

Here is the working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/632d0af0e3431d893a8c7105e7621cea58872216).

**EDIT** :
As per requirement, please check below snippet.

```
while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $temp =  array_map('utf8_encode', $selected_row);
    $temp_row = ['id'=> $temp['id'], 'column' => $temp['column']];
    array_push($rows, $temp_row);
}
```

Comment: sorry i must have write wrong in the comment. THis is a result of select. I want to add another key value on every row return.

Comment: Can you update your question as per that? Because I am not clear now

Comment: in the columns there will be many i only added example of ID i just want to add that column name in the result set i dont want to recreate the array just add one pair

Comment: Agreed. Then please update your desired output. Because, that's how we are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry but i already addedd the desired output like this `[{
    "id": "000060000000000071964708\/17\/201309:55:00",
    "column": "pcchrgcod"
}]`

Comment: That's how my snippet is giving output which is edit version of my answer, have you tried it? You just need to json_encode to get the json version of my array

Comment: im just worried that it will be slow when there are many rows in result?plus in your example i need to put all the columns but i dont want that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155305/discussion-between-rahul-meshram-and-martin).